# MySQLConnector c# update MySqlCommand parameters

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, mysql-connector

I have a foreach loop in C# wich execute a MySql command to check if the result exist, the problem is I dont know how to update the value in the parameters corresponding to `@id_line` an error is thrown at the second iteration

```
foreach (String[] infos in ReferenceLine.getList())
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_line", infos[0].ToString());
    using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.HasRows) { return true; }
    }
}
```

> I thought of checking if the value exist and deleting it but I dont find this solution **clean**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the declaration of the parameter outside the loop without giving an explicit value, then inside the loop just update the Value property without redeclaring the parameter

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_line", "");
foreach (String[] infos in ReferenceLine.getList())
{

    cmd.Parameters["@id_line"].Value = infos[0].ToString();
    using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.HasRows) { return true; }
    }
}
```

However, it seems possible to completely avoid this loop with a more precise query with a WHERE condition.

Consider also to use

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@id_line", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
```

instead of AddWithValue. AddWithValue [has some drawbacks](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) that suggest to limit its use.